# InfoPath Preview to PDF

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, pdf

I have InfoPath designer file (.xsn), was able to open it with corresponding XML data file. But having problem saving it as PDF or any other format.

Any ideas how to save Preview InfoPath File to PDF

Answer (score 2):

**How to save Preview InfoPath File to PDF**

- Click on the **preview** button.
- Click on `File` Menu > `Info`.
- Click on `Publish as PDF or XSP` to export your form preview with its data to PDF file format.

[image]

- Select your local location on your computer to save the preview form as PDF.

**[OutPut]**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me, it just creates blank PDF